# Почему не работает мой код

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Извините не по теме можно на сайте эту ... выключить ?
Мы в этом отношении еще не Европа !!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
var headerList = document.querySelector('.header-list');

button.onclick = function() {
  headerList.classList.toggle('openMneu');
};
```

```css
.openMneu {
  display: none;
}

.header {
  background-color: #13334c;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger .fa-bars {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px);
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: 50%;
}

.logo {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo__link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-list__item {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 26px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.header-list__item:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

.header-list__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class='nav'>
  <ul class="header-list">
    <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Услуги</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Примеры</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>О нас</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Контакты</li>
  </ul>
  <button class='hamburger'>
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: А что он должен делать?

Comment: @meine при клике на haburger открывать меню мне надо в media   прописать

Comment: в меню есть кнопка с часами для отключения: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8907/177221

Comment: Знаете, в Канаде ещё почище, чем в Европе. Но чем Вам единорог-то не угодил? Он у меня ассоциируется с девственницами... Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Порядок объявления стилей:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
var headerList = document.querySelector('.header-list');

button.onclick = function() {
  headerList.classList.toggle('openMneu');
};
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #13334c;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger .fa-bars {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px);
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: 50%;
}

.logo {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo__link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.openMneu {
  display: none;
}

.header-list__item {
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 26px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.header-list__item:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

.header-list__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class='nav'>
  <ul class="header-list">
    <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Услуги</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Примеры</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>О нас</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Контакты</li>
  </ul>
  <button class='hamburger'>Click
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </button>
</nav>
```

или более специфический стиль:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
var headerList = document.querySelector('.header-list');

button.onclick = function() {
  headerList.classList.toggle('openMneu');
};
```

```css
.openMneu.openMneu {
  display: none;
}

.header {
  background-color: #13334c;
}

.hamburger {
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger .fa-bars {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 8px);
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: 50%;
}

.logo {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.logo__link {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.header-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
  -ms-flex-pack: end;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-list__item {
  /*color: #ffffff;*/
  font-family: Philosopher;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 26px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}

.header-list__item:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
}

.header-list__item:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav class='nav'>
  <ul class="header-list">
    <li class="header-list__item"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Услуги</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Примеры</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>О нас</li>
    <li class="header-list__item">
      <a href="#"></a>Контакты</li>
  </ul>
  <button class='hamburger'>Click
       <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </button>
</nav>
```

Comment: спасибо, у Вас все работает, а почему у меня нет ? 2) В media тоже будет работать ?

Comment: @user332017 Найдите 10 отличий :). Я написал в ответе.

Comment: скажите пожалуйста когда откат будет прежней версии, а то смотреть на эту ... больше 5 минут не могу ?

Comment: @user332017 Я тоже не могу. Печатаю с закрытыми глазами.

Comment: я понял класс который мы добaвляем в js надо в конец. Скажите пожалуйста это все или еще есть подводные камни ?

Comment: спасибо, я не могу в слепую печать; А когда откат будет знаете ? и будет ли вообще ?

Comment: @user332017, вверху есть кнопка с часиками, надо на неё нажать.

Comment: @Something спасибо,  а с  чего поставили такое счастье?

Comment: К первому апреля вроде бы